# Digit product of a number

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, iteration

I want to practice writing a function (recursive and iterative) to give a product of a given number by multiplying its **non-zero digits**.

for example: 22 = 2x2 which gives you 4
and
303 = 3x3 which gives you 9

most of the solutions I found here won't really work if there is a zero in the number.

I tried the following using iterative, but still do not understand how I can code it using a recursive method.

```
def digitProductI(n):
    product = 1
    while n > 0:
        remainder = n%10
        if remainder != 0:
            product *= remainder
        n = n//10

    return product
```

Comment: Here's a question to guide you: If you have a number with the digits `d(N) d(N-1) ... d(1) d(0)`, how can you get the product of all digits if you have the digit `d(0)` and the product of the digits `d(N) d(N-1) ... d(1)` (the result of a recursive call)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make your function a recursive function, you'll need a few things:

1. The function calling itself
2. A base case

For your function, instead of using a while loop, you can call the function itself with the new product and return that value. Then, to prevent a [`RecursionError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#RecursionError), you should add a base case, which in this case is returning n if n <= 0. Writing this inn code would look something like this:

```py
def digitProductI(n):

    # This is the base case. If n is 0, it would return 1.
    if not n:
        return 1

    # If n is non-zero, we find the remainder and call the function again with the floor divided value.
    remainder = n % 10
    if remainder:
        product = remainder
    else:
        product = 1
    return product * digitProductI(n // 10)
```

This would yield the same results as your original function. Just like in your function, a zero input would yield 1 as the result, and captive zeroes and trailing zeroes would be ignored.

Comment: This will not work for `n = 0`.

Comment: Thanks Jeff,  It was helpful! how can we enhance the code in order to get a final digit product. (i.e. 808 = 8x8 = 64 = 6x4= 24 = 2x4 = 8)